# Conditional where clause in SQL using Cognos 10

Tags: sql, cognos

I have a cogons report where there is a custom sql query written. I have about 10 statements in the where cluase. 2 of the statements i want to execute based on a condition.
I wrote my code as :

```
#promptmany('Skills','integer') is not null and ( #promptmany('Skills','integer',' ','and SES.STSKL_ID in (','',')')#
                AND ISNULL(ses.stempskl_start_date, '1900-01-01') <= DATEADD(DAY, 13, CAST(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(#prompt('Work Date','string')#, '-', ''), 1, 8) AS datetime))
                ) 
                OR
                #promptmany('Skills','integer') is null and ( #promptmany('Skills','integer',' ','and SES.STSKL_ID in (','',')')#
```

`#promptmany` is not accepting the null condition check. Please help

Comment: Second part makes your logic unclear. You are checking Skills is null and have value same time. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong:

1. Macro functions should start and end with a pound (#). You can't nest macros as you've done here
2. The pound signs should be around a single macro expression. You have boolean clauses inside yours.

Each part that you want Cognos to insert a prompt should be enclosed by pounds like this:

```
#promptmany('Skills','integer')#
```

The idea is for Cognos to insert a value into the SQL before passing it to the data source. Any SQL should be outside of the macro expressions.